determine which system modules were loaded
I'm trying to determine which python system modules are loaded:
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: l = sorted(list(sys.modules.keys()))
In [3]: 'json' in l
Out[3]: True

According to the docs:

This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been loaded.

So I thought that maybe sys imports json, but this turns out wrong:
In [4]: json.dumps({'oren': 12})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 json.dumps({'oren': 12})

NameError: name 'json' is not defined

What am I missing?

So is it correct to say that sys.modules is the comprehensive set of all modules that come natively with python?

No, that's not correct at all; it's the modules that have been loaded, as the documentation that you quote clearly states. Until you've loaded it, "json" not in sys.modules. Python doesn't automatically load every standard library module. And loaded modules that don't come natively also appear in sys.modules.

So it seems that a better formulation would be: "which modules are loaded?"

@ekhumoro if I understand you correctly, the exact specification of what is loaded is very vague (if it even exists ?) and depends on the host / version etc. ?

@OrenIshShalom Certainly it will depend on the version - but I'm not sure about the platform. To find out, I suggest you run this: python -c 'import sys; print(len(sys.modules)); print(" ".join(sorted(sys.modules)))'. On my Linux system, this does not seem to show anything platform-specific (see the following comment for details).

@OrenIshShalom PPS: I forgot about the site module. After adding the -S option, I get: 23 __main__ _abc _codecs _frozen_importlib _frozen_importlib_external _imp _io _signal _thread _warnings _weakref abc builtins codecs encodings encodings.aliases encodings.utf_8 io marshal posix sys time zipimport.

@OrenIshShalom yes the list of “what gets loaded automatically” is not specified and is dependent on environment. For example, the file ~/.pythonstartup will be read and executed as part of the default interactive interpreter’s startup process, and that can be customized to import whatever you want. As noted above, IPython imports many more packages than vanilla Python. At the end of the day, if you want a particular module, just import it yourself. There’s almost no cost to importing a module a second time as it will just reuse what’s in sys.modules.

sys.modules lists every module that has been loaded into the current interpreter process. Notably, it doesn’t only list “system” modules, but rather every loaded module - whether it’s a core module or a third-party one. It also doesn’t list modules until they’ve been loaded (usually via an import statement in some other loaded module).
This is distinct from the list of names that have been imported into your current scope via an import statement. Only names that have been imported can be used directly. The import statement can import specific names from a module (e.g. from json import dumps) and/or rename imports (e.g. import json as j). Both of these are reflected in the local symbol table corresponding to the scope of the import statement, but not in the sys.modules - in both of those cases, only the module json would be in sys.modules.
If you want to know what’s accessible to your current scope, try the vars() function. This lists every name in scope, including imported names.
If you want to know what modules ship with Python, your best bet is to consult the documentation. You can check the lib/python3.x directory that comes with your Python distribution, but that won’t be complete (omits some built-in modules) and will include many modules that are only for internal use.

so what determines which modules are loaded? specifically, regarding third party code, when I do a pip install X, does it mean that X will be loaded from now on?

Installing a module only means that it becomes available for import (by being installed in a location that is searched when executing an import statement). By the way, if you’re curious about what gets imported, you can use the -v flag to Python (e.g. python3 -v <script>) to have the interpreter list all the modules as they are loaded.
